# Is it possiable to set the reply-to address in a mailitem using c#

Tags: c#, mailitem

Is it possible to set the Reply To address of a mailitem in c#?

As in `mailitem.reply();` then set the reply to so that all messages once replied to by the recipient come into a central mail box?

I’ve spent some time Googling but with no luck. I’m probably looking for something that isn’t possible or looking in the wrong place.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's the ReplyRecipients you're looking for?