# Set "reply-to" address in windows forms using interop office outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, winforms-interop

To send emails we are using interop office outlook in window application and this means we can set `to`,`cc`,`bcc` but I am not able to set the `REPLY-TO` address (address at which email receiver will reply).

I want the `REPLY-TO` address be different from original sender address, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: no formatting help needed please !!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possiable to set the reply-to address in a mailitem using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791477/is-it-possiable-to-set-the-reply-to-address-in-a-mailitem-using-c-sharp)

Comment: [Did you even google this](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&es_sm=93&q=c%23+set+reply+to+address+in+outlook&oq=c%23+set+reply+to+address+in+outlook&gs_l=serp.3...21271.40280.0.41746.46.34.11.0.0.3.189.3731.10j24.34.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..20.26.1786.WZ2_kAGjdyI)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the MailItem.ReplyRecipients collection to a add a reply-to address.